# Duplicated case statement in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

there has to be a better way to do this here, right?

```
(format t "Enter your age: ~%")

(defun age-case (age)
  (case age
    (1 (format t "You belong in Kindergarden~%"))
    (2 (format t "You belong in Kindergarden~%"))
    (3 (format t "You belong in Kindergarden~%"))
    (4 (format t "You belong in Kindergarden~%"))
    (5 (format t "You belong in Preschool~%"))
    (6 (format t "Elementary school ~%"))
    (t (format t "Somewhere else"))))

(defvar *age* (read))

(age-case *age*)
```

In Python I would use a case 1..4 for this, in C++, Java and co. I would maybe use a falltrough switch case where I leave out the break for cases 1 to 3. Is there a neat little trick to do this in clisp w/o the code duplication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `case` clause can accept multiple keys:

```lisp
(defun age-case (age)
  (case age
    ((1 2 3 4) (format t "You belong in Kindergarden~%"))
    (5 (format t "You belong in Preschool~%"))
    (6 (format t "Elementary school ~%"))
    (t (format t "Somewhere else"))))
```

Rainer's solution used ranges provided in the `integer` type with a `typecase`:

```
(typecase age
  ((integer 1 4) 'one-to-four)
  ((eql 5)       'five)
  ((eql 6)       'six)
  (t             'something-else)))
```

Building on this, you can do type checking "for free":

```
(etypecase age
  ((integer 1 4) 'one-to-four)
  ((eql 5)       'five)
  ((eql 6)       'six)
  ((integer 7 *) 'something-else)))
```

Alternatively, you can also use `cond`:

```lisp
(cond
  ((<= 1 age 100) 'one-to-ahundred)
  ;; ...and so on.
  )
```

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use type specifiers:

```
CL-USER > (let ((age 6))
            (typecase age
              ((integer 1 4) 'one-to-four)   ; integers from 1 to 4
              ((eql 5)       'five)
              ((eql 6)       'six)
              (t             'something-else)))
SIX
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cond](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm) and [member](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm) like this:

```
(defun age-test ()
  (format t "Enter your age: ~%")
  (finish-output)
  (let ((age (read)))
    (format t (cond ((member age '(1 2 3 4)) "You belong in Kindergarden~%")
                    ((= age 5) "You belong in Preschool~%")
                    ((= age 6) "Elementary school ~%")
                    (t "Somewhere else")))))

(age-test)
```

Comment: Also `(<= 1 age 4)` to stay similar to the other comparisons.